# Delete from table is too slow Mysql Percona

Tags: mysql, percona

Please suggest

I have to low speed for delete records from DB
For example: for InnoDB table with 2 000 000 records  Command "DELETE FROM mytable; take over 2 minutes.

I thinks it is too low.

Have any idea how to fix it and speed up ?

Server configuration :

32GB Ram
Server version: 5.6.27-76.0-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 76.0, Revision 5498987

DELL PowerEdge™ R730 DX291 
240 GB 6 Gb/s SSD

```
    BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 17582522368; in additional pool allocated 0
Total memory allocated by read views 3032
Internal hash tables (constant factor + variable factor)
    Adaptive hash index 2754082160      (302769416 + 2451312744)
    Page hash           4426024 (buffer pool 0 only)
    Dictionary cache    75682369        (70804688 + 4877681)
    File system         1058056         (812272 + 245784)
    Lock system         58954776        (42500456 + 16454320)
    Recovery system     0       (0 + 0)
Dictionary memory allocated 4877681
Buffer pool size        1048572
Buffer pool size, bytes 17179803648
Free buffers            4123
Database pages          893830
Old database pages      329867
Modified db pages       12582
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2701636, not young 31973635
4.15 youngs/s, 0.82 non-youngs/s
Pages read 813409, created 431679, written 4701725
0.35 reads/s, 1.05 creates/s, 4.52 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 893830, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[908]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size        262143
Buffer pool size, bytes 4294950912
Free buffers            1026
Database pages          223314
Old database pages      82414
Modified db pages       3295
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 536380, not young 8933922
0.75 youngs/s, 0.30 non-youngs/s
Pages read 220386, created 103249, written 1751238
0.12 reads/s, 0.27 creates/s, 1.55 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 223314, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[227]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size        262143
Buffer pool size, bytes 4294950912
Free buffers            1036
Database pages          223526
Old database pages      82492
Modified db pages       3036
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 796430, not young 11552187
0.70 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 197712, created 106527, written 967751
0.05 reads/s, 0.30 creates/s, 1.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 223526, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[227]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size        262143
Buffer pool size, bytes 4294950912
Free buffers            1031
Database pages          223501
Old database pages      82483
Modified db pages       3428
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 683609, not young 6396164
1.87 youngs/s, 0.10 non-youngs/s
Pages read 195760, created 111577, written 925981
0.07 reads/s, 0.22 creates/s, 1.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 223501, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[227]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size        262143
Buffer pool size, bytes 4294950912
Free buffers            1030
Database pages          223489
Old database pages      82478
Modified db pages       2823
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 685217, not young 5091362
0.82 youngs/s, 0.42 non-youngs/s
Pages read 199551, created 110326, written 1056755
0.10 reads/s, 0.25 creates/s, 0.97 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 223489, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[227]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
7 read views open inside InnoDB
8 RW transactions active inside InnoDB
0 RO transactions active inside InnoDB
8 out of 1000 descriptors used
---OLDEST VIEW---
Normal read view
Read view low limit trx n:o 611342990
Read view up limit trx id 611342990
Read view low limit trx id 611342990
Read view individually stored trx ids:
-----------------
Main thread process no. 5665, id 139640581388032, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 55207878, updated 246281303, deleted 51033866, read 177397767449
60.07 inserts/s, 9.02 updates/s, 8.60 deletes/s, 425076.70 reads/s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Truncate table instead of Delete. It is much much faster. To be able to use it, you have to drop all the constrains on the table. Simple you can do it in 3 steps:
1. Drop constrains
2. Truncate the table
3. Create constrains